# IF Function does not show false

Tags: excel, if-statement

Newbie in Stackoverflow.

Question 1.  Am doing an IF formula in Excel but the resulting cell computes and returns a true data each time and no false is recognized.  Here are the values

`K4` is `1` and `L4` is `10`

I want `M4` to show:

1. If `K4>=6`
2. Then `M4` must show `K4` plus (`L4` divided by 12 months)
3. Or show `Not Eligible` if false

Here, my `M4` is showing `1.833` instead of `Not Eligible`.  I am using this formula in `M4`, `IF(K4>=6, SUM(K4+(L4/12), "0"))`

Question 2.  How can I make the 6 in Q1.1 constant without having to type it and drag the formula in the affected cell?  Can't put it in a cell, say put it in `A1` and create the Q1.1 as `K4>=$A$1`.

Comment: How about including a sample xls file?

Comment: You can't be getting 1.833 if you are using `K4>=6` and `K4=1` do you mean `K4<=6`?

Comment: Also I do not believe you should have that `SUM` function in there, for you are summing `K4+(L4/12)` and `"0"` you probably are wanting `IF(K4>=6, K4+(L4/12), "Not Eligible")`

Answer (score 0):

i'm betting that the value in cell `K4` is a string. so try something like:

```
if(K4*1>=6, ...)
```

you can check out the type with `type`

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your formula

```
IF(
K4>=6
, SUM(K4+(L4/12), "0")    <~~~ SUM that makes no sense
        <~~~ no statement in the ELSE part
)
```

I think you meant something like

```
IF(K4>=6, K4+(L4/12), "Not Eligible")
```

There's no need to `SUM` anything because you are already adding your two values together. Your `SUM` amounted to `SUM(5)` or whatever.